# How can I create a dictionary with a-z and 0-9 up to 8 characters long and save it as a .txt file?

Tags: c#, int, var

Me and a friend have been messing around with this, and with a good bit of research I have not been able to figure this out, granted I know nothing about c#. What we have so far is this

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int length = 8; length > 0; length--)
        {
            var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var q = alphabet.Select(x => x.ToString());
            int size = length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
                q = q.SelectMany(x => alphabet, (x, y) => x + y);

            foreach (var item in q)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
} //namespace end
```

It creates everything we want it to ( I believe), but our only problem is we're not to sure how to save it. Might be due to lack of sleep, but we can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter for saving files.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are just using this to create a rainbow table you might just want to download a proper one: http://project-rainbowcrack.com/table.htm

Comment: That would take all the fun out of it :).
Thanks for the link though!

Comment: True :-) And it would probably cost a bit. But as far as I know you can also find some decent tables on BitTorrent.

Comment: I may take a look, could save me some time and processing power :D

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
```

> example:

```
int number;
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/[yourpath]");
for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
  sw.WriteLine(i);
}
```

this is an example .. make it yours! i'd sure like to know updates! mabey you will make a more sophisticated or better one!